# Static site works on Bitballoon, but not on Github Pages

Tags: javascript, github, static

I created a site that is hosted on Bitballoon.com
http://stephanie-heintzman.bitballoon.com/

We took the exact same directory and added it to Github pages.
For some reason, the site works but the video background is broken.
http://stephanieheintzman.com/

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see what's wrong. But if you have trouble loading external resources (<script src=...>, <link href=.../>, etc.), you may want to use a <base/> tag. When I started working with GitHub Pages, my URLs were all broken because I wanted to load `username.github.io/projectname/file.js`, but instead a request was being made to `username.github.io/file.js`. I fixed this with `<base href="/projectname/"/>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem. It was a problem with case sensitivity.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ytplayer.css">
```

needed to be

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/YTPlayer.css">
```